# Nginx rate limit PHP files only

Tags: nginx

I am aware that one can apply rate limiting to PHP files like so:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    ....
}
```

However, since my nginx server works are reverse proxy server, it does not actually know when a PHP file is loaded since my urls don't include the .php extension.

so if I load http://myurl/products it will just see "products" and not "products.php". So for that reason the location directive does not apply. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Put rate limit on server that does know what urls are passed to PHP

Comment: Or use a url pattern, if there is a pattern, which _does_ permit nginx to "know" if the request is static or a dynamic request.